# HttpURLConnection not returning content

Tags: android

Im trying to connect to a webservice in my localhost but. HttpConnection is not returning content.
look at the code and the comments. it seems that getContentLenght is returning -1. but when I check my webservices its returning json values.

```
package medapp.app;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by MacBookPro on 5/4/14.
 */
public class PostActivity extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... arg0){

        int responseCode = -1;

        //PostActivity getBlogPostsTask = new PostActivity();
        try
        {
            URL blogFeedUrl = new URL("http://localhost/medapp/public/mobile/post");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) blogFeedUrl.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == 200)
            {
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();// connection getting -1
                char[] charArray = new char[contentLength]; //This is where error occurs.
                reader.read(charArray);
                String responseData = new String(charArray);
                Log.v("TAG", responseData);

            }
            else
            {
                Log.i("TAG", "Unsuccessful HTTP Response Code: " + responseCode);
            }



        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            Log.e("TAG", "exception caught: ", e);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e("TAG", "exception caught: ", e);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("TAG", "exception caught: ", e);
        }


        return "Code: " + responseCode;
    }
}
```

Here is my log file

```
05-04 12:48:17.251    2358-2371/medapp.app E/TAG﹕ exception caught:
    java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -1
            at medapp.app.PostActivity.doInBackground(PostActivity.java:38)
            at medapp.app.PostActivity.doInBackground(PostActivity.java:17)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html):

> Returns the content length in bytes specified by the response header
>   field content-length or -1 if this field is not set.
>
> Returns the value of the response header field content-length.

At the top, there's also this disclaimer:

> By default, this implementation of HttpURLConnection requests that
>   servers use gzip compression. Since getContentLength() returns the
>   number of bytes transmitted, you cannot use that method to predict how
>   many bytes can be read from getInputStream(). Instead, read that
>   stream until it is exhausted: when read() returns -1

The last line has the solution to your problem.

Comment: sorry so how can I get the content size? im new in android development thanks